# How to host a next.js react project using IIS on Windows Server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, windows, iis, next.js

We want to host the application on IIS server. We need it to support dynamic routing.
We tried downloading IIS node and we're not sure how to proceed.

Is there a file that needs to be loaded and needed to run, such as server.js?

Comment: All you need is just `web.config` and HttpPlatformHandler, https://halfblood.pro/running-nodejs-web-apps-on-iis-with-httpplatformhandler/#nextjs Much simpler than the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to install nodejs on the host system and have server running on  a port, then use IIS as a reverse proxy on top.

This article goes into detailed steps on how to get there - https://alex.domenici.net/archive/deploying-a-node-js-application-on-windows-iis-using-a-reverse-proxy

Comment: I followed this but getting a "This page can't be displayed" when I click on "browse website". Node is already installed and server is running.